# Docker: image was found but does not match the specified platform (attempting to build amd64 on Apple M1)

Tags: docker, docker-compose, apple-m1

Disclaimer: I am new to Docker and am aware of my ignorance.

I am trying to build a Docker container with the amd64 architecture on computer with Apple's M1 Pro. I have specified `platform: linux/amd64` in the `docker-compose.yml` as well as `FROM --platform=linux/amd64` in the Dockerfile (both simultaneously and individually).

If I include it in the Dockerfile for that container, it builds fine but `uname -a` in that shell shows `aarch64` architecture (not `x86_64`).

If I include it in `docker-compose.yml`, I get the following error:

```
Error response from daemon: image with reference api:latest was found but does not match the specified platform: wanted linux/amd64, actual: linux/arm64/v8
```

where `api` is one of the containers I am trying to build with `docker-compose`.

File Structure:

```
.
├── api
│   ├── Dockerfile-API
│   ├── entrypoint.sh
│   └── ...
├── db
│   └── ...
├── docker-compose.yml
└── nginx
    └── ...
```

`./docker-compose.yml`:

```yaml
version: '3.0'
services:
  db:
    ...
  api:
    platform: linux/amd64 # line in question
    build:
      context: ./api
      dockerfile: Dockerfile-API
    command: ./run.sh
    depends_on:
      - db
    env_file: local.env
    networks:
      - nginx_network
    expose:
      - "8000"
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    image: api:latest
    ...
  nginx:
    ...

networks:
  nginx_network:
    external: true

volumes:
  ...
```

`./api/Dockerfile-API`

```
FROM --platform=linux/amd64 python3.6 # line in question
...
```

From directory `.` with platform set in `docker-compose.yml`:

```bash
$ docker-compose down
$ docker-compose up
Error response from daemon: image with reference api:latest was found but does not match the specified platform: wanted linux/amd64, actual: linux/arm64/v8
```

From directory `.` with platform set in `./api/Dockerfile-API`:

```bash
$ docker-compose down
$ docker-compose up -d
$ docker-compose exec api bash
> uname -a
Linux bc17e565c265 5.10.104-linuxkit #1 SMP PREEMPT Thu Mar 17 17:05:54 UTC 2022 aarch64 GNU/Linux
```

I am grateful for any ideas/suggestions about why this is happening and how to fix it. Rosetta 2 is installed on my machine and Docker is up-to-date. Thank you!

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 11):

It turns out that `docker-compose down` is **not** equivalent with deleting an image. After deleting the `api` image through the Docker Desktop GUI then re-building (`docker-compose up`), I was able to create the container with `x86_64` architecture.

Comment: You can also do `up --build` to force a re-build of the image, see https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/compose_up/#options — note that when not using `docker-compose` but just `docker build`, I had to add `--no-cache` to the options to force it to start from the AMD64 image.